# Enable plain text email outlook 2003

Tags: windows-server-2008, outlook, outlook-2003

I have an outlook 2003 exchange server, a 2008 domain controller and windows xp clients connected.  It is required that the nodes have disabled the option for plain text emails.  We want to force all emails in plain text and ensure that option has been grayed out.  I know I can create a local group policy to do this with an .adm file but how can I push this out to all users with a gpupdate /force.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ugh.  You don't create group policy with an adm file.  Those are template files that allow you to make a set of configurations through GPO that you otherwise wouldn't be able to.  Such as, for example, forcing Outlook 2003 to use plain text mode for email.

1. [Download the Office 2003 Administrative Templates for GPO](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=9035).  (Assuming SP3)
2. [Follow Technet guide to force plain text emails via GPO in Outlook 2003.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/930508)
3. Wait for GPO to apply.  (Or use `gpupdate /force` on client machines.)

Answer (score 1):

Group Policy settings don't get "pushed" to clients. Group Policy settings are "pulled" by the clients by the GP CSE's. The GP refresh interval for user settings (which is what an Office GPO setting is) occurs every 90 minutes by default (with a random 0 to 30 minute offset), so they'll "pull" the new settings within 90 minutes or so of your changes.